# Can't get query results from a bundled Realm

Tags: ios, database, cocoa, realm

I'm trying to bundle my app with a pre-generated Realm file that I created (with the same models) in a separate target.

Following the instructions in [bundling a realm with an app](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#bundling-a-realm-with-an-app), I created a compacted version of the DB with -[RLMRealm writeCopyToPath:error:] and copied into my app's bundle.

The Realm filename is data.Realm. The data is for read-only access, so I didn't copy it into the documents directory, but left it in the bundle instead.

The problem is that my non-default Realm is not returning any query results, although the Realm file contains the entries. There are no errors when initializing the Realm, so I don't think it is a file access problem.

This is the code to run a test query on the Realm:

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *rlmConfig = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
NSString *DBpath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"realm"];
rlmConfig.path = DBpath;
rlmConfig.readOnly = YES;
NSError *err;
realm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:rlmConfig error:&err];
if (err)
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",err);
Person *result = [[Person allObjects] firstObject];
NSLog(@"first Person: %@",result.name); //Empty - No results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the default realm to my configuration with:

```
RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:rlmConfig];
```

Then I simply loaded this "default" Realm, which is using my bundled file.

```
[RLMRealm defaultRealm]
```